# create soap request from wsdl code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

After searching long on SO, I am not able to find any solution for creating SOAP request from WSDL in C# or JAVA or any language.

I have seen many tools which did it very well like SoapUI etc.

But looking for some code which can create the "SOAP Request from WSDL"

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about from a testing perspective?

Comment: not exactly but want to generate soap request template dynamically.

Comment: found a code in JAVA http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model-doc/1.4/java-api/create-soap-request-template.htm any reference in C#?